# is a good idea to sample a big dataset and run pca on it?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

Suppose that we have a dataset with many rows and that we can't afford to run PCA many times due to constraints.
In this regard, I have two questions:

1. Is it a good idea to take a sample from the data, run PCA on it to find a good number of components then use this number on the whole dataset?
2. Is it ok to take the subspace  built using this sample dataset and transform the original data using it?

Comment: Why would you want to run PCA many times? All you need is the covariance matrix of the entire data

Comment: Well, one simple scenario would be  to be sure to select a good number of dimensions.

Comment: First, you run PCA on the whole data. Second, you select the number of components.

Comment: Plus, PCA won't change no matter how many times you run it (assuming you run it on the same data, and in the case of PCA the more data the better), so you'd only run it once even if you wanted to select a set of dimesions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it a good idea to take a sample from the data, run PCA on it to find a good number of components then use this number on the whole
>      dataset?

PCA does eigendecomposition of covariance matrix - it doesn't actually need to run on the whole dataset, if your covariance estimate from sample is good.

> 2. Is it ok to take the subspace built using this sample dataset and transform the original data using it?

Yes, provided that the covariance estimate is OK.